# Kendo UI Editor - Remove a specific tool from editor-menu

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How can I remove a specific tool/button from Kendo Editor control?

Actually, I just want to remove `Insert image` button from [Kendo Editor(all tools)](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/editor/all-tools.html) control.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
  .Name("editor")
  .Tools(tools => tools.SubScript().SuperScript().ViewHtml())
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it. Need to remove all the tools first of all, and then add each tool one by one. There is a method `Clear()` for it. Here is the code.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
    .Name(name)
    .Tools(tools => tools.Clear()                    //remove all tools
    .Bold().Italic().Underline().Strikethrough()
    .FontName().FontSize().FontColor().BackColor()
    .JustifyLeft().JustifyCenter().JustifyRight().JustifyFull()
    .InsertUnorderedList().InsertOrderedList().Indent().Outdent()
    .FormatBlock().CreateLink().Unlink()
    .SubScript().SuperScript().ViewHtml()
)
```

Please let me know if there is any other way of doing this.

Comment: There is a missing parentheses somewhere.  Suspect it belongs after `ViewHtml()`  Otherwise, very helpful answer!

Answer (score 2):

The other way to remove the specific or all tools is by using jquery, something like this -

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#editor").kendoEditor({
            value: "<p>hello there...</p>",
            tools: []
        });
    });

</script>
```

and here is the [**Demo JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t90rymm2/)